# generate or predict different possible test cases

Tags: java

I was wishing to know that how am i supposed to know where my program is going wrong.The problem below is an assignment and has to be submitted online.However out of the 10 test cases my solution works for the first 6 .The other four give a **wrong answer** as an output.The test Cases are not given or shown to the participants.So could people tell me how should a generate my own set of test Cases for the problem below to know for which scenarios my code is failing?

Description:

```
Given M busy-time slots of N people, You need to print all the available time slots when all the N people can schedule a meeting for a duration of K minutes.
Event time will be of form HH MM ( where 0 <= HH <= 23 and 0 <= MM <= 59 ), K will be in the form minutes.

    Input Format:

    M K [ M number of busy time slots , K is the duration in minutes ]
    Followed by M lines with 4 numbers on each line.

Each line will be of form StartHH StartMM EndHH EndMM  [ Example 9Am-11Am time slot will be given as 9 00 11 00 ]
An event time slot is of form [Start Time, End Time ) . Which means it inclusive at start time but doesn’t include the end time. 
So an event of form 10 00  11 00 => implies that the meeting start at 10:00 and ends at 11:00, so another meeting can start at 11:00.

    Sample Input:
    5 120
    16 00 17 00
    10 30 14 30
    20 45 22 15
    10 00 13 15
    09 00 11 00

    Sample Output:
    00 00 09 00
    17 00 20 45

    Sample Input:
    8 60
    08 00 10 15
    22 00 23 15
    17 00 19 00
    07 00 09 45
    09 00 13 00
    16 00 17 45
    12 00 13 30
    11 30 12 30

    Sample Output:
    00 00 07 00
    13 30 16 00
    19 00 22 00

Constraints :
1 <= M <= 100

Note: 24 00 has to be presented as 00 00.
```

I dont want a solution as i already have one(though not exactly perfect) but just that how should a generate my own set of test cases?I am using Java.My question is related as to how to test my code?

My Solution as Requested:-

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> stime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static StringTokenizer str = null;
    static int limit;
    static int[] timeArr = new int[1440];
    ArrayList<Integer> time = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        initialize(timeArr);
        String line = scan.nextLine().toString();
        str = new StringTokenizer(line);
        int trials;
        trials = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken().toString());
        limit = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken().toString());
        int startHr,startMin,endHr,endMin,startTime,endTime;
        for(int i=0;i<trials;i++)
            {
                line = scan.nextLine().toString();
                str = new StringTokenizer(line);
                startHr = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
                startMin = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
                startTime = startHr*60 + startMin;
                endHr = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
                endMin = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
                if(endHr==00 && endMin == 00)
                    {
                        endHr = 23;
                        endMin = 60;
                    }
                endTime = (endHr*60 + endMin);
                //System.out.println(startHr + ":" + startMin + " to " + endHr + ":" + endMin + " is " + startTime + " to " + endTime);
                fillSlots(startTime,endTime);

            }
        //display();
        fillMap();
        //display();
        limitMap();
        toProperTime();
    }
    private static void toProperTime() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int starthr,startmin,endhr,endmin;
        for(int i=0;i<stime.size();i++)
            {
                starthr = (stime.get(i))/60;
                startmin = (stime.get(i))%60;
                if(map.get(stime.get(i))==1439)
                    {
                        endhr = (map.get(stime.get(i)) + 1)%24;
                        endmin = (map.get(stime.get(i)) + 1)%24;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        endhr = (map.get(stime.get(i)) + 1)/60;
                        endmin = (map.get(stime.get(i)) + 1)%60;
                    }


                System.out.println(getTime(starthr) + " " + getTime(startmin) + " " + getTime(endhr) + " " + getTime(endmin));
            }
    }
    private static void fillMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int counter = 0;
        int endTime ,startTime,currentTime ;
        boolean loop1 = false;
        boolean loop2 =false;
        while(counter<1440)
            {
                //System.out.println(counter);
                currentTime = counter;
                while((counter<1440)&&timeArr[counter]!=1)
                    {
                        loop1 = true;
                        if((counter==1439) || timeArr[counter] == 1)
                            {
                                endTime = counter;
                                counter++;
                                break;
                            }
                        counter++;
                    }
                if((loop1==true)&&(loop2==false))
                    {
                        stime.add(currentTime);
                        map.put(currentTime,counter-1);
                    }

                while((counter<1440)&&timeArr[counter]!=0)
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                loop1 = false;



            }

    }
    private static void displayMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<stime.size();i++)
            System.out.println(stime.get(i) +" till " + map.get(stime.get(i)));
    }
    private static void limitMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<stime.size();i++)
            {
                if((map.get(stime.get(i)) - stime.get(i)) + 1 < limit)
                    {
                        map.remove(stime.get(i));
                        stime.remove(i);
                    }
            }
    }
    private static void display() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<timeArr.length;i++)
            {
                if((i)%60==0)
                    System.out.println();
                System.out.print(timeArr[i]);
            }
    }
    private static void initialize(int[] timeArr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<timeArr.length;i++)
            {
                timeArr[i] = 0;
            }
    }
    private static void fillSlots(int startTime,int endTime) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i =startTime;i<endTime;i++)
            {
                timeArr[i] = 1;
            }
    }

    private static String  getTime(int x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        NumberFormat format=NumberFormat.getInstance();  
        format.setMaximumIntegerDigits(2);  
        format.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);  
        return format.format(x).replace(",","")  ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your use of multiple unrelated language tags is ridiculous. Please choose ***one*** and only one language tag. Else voting to close as an overly broad and ambiguous question. If the question is not language specific, then get rid of the language tags or you will seem to be spamming tags.

Comment: I think you need to use a debugger and step through your program. Check each point to make sure your logic is correct.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tag Java

Comment: And you don't show your solution code. How are we to guess what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels He didn't ask us to help him find the program's problem. He asked us how to help him generate test cases. That seems a little different.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The code is a bit undocumented.I apologise.

Comment: @LeeMeador I agree with you.

Comment: As an aside, please use consistent formatting. You are working with Java, you really should use Egyptian curly braces. I understand that some people hate those and prefer c-style braces. However, **please** be consistent.

Comment: @LeeMeador: thanks for the clarification. 1+ to your answer by the way.

Comment: @supersam654 Consistent is the key. Either put all the beginning curly braces on the end of the line. Or put them on the next line. If the next line, either indent them on the next line by one indent or line them up with that previous line. On the closing curly brace, either line it up with the opening brace or the line it ends OR line it up with the indented section. This, like your personal religion or lack of one, should be chosen carefully and not changed lightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to generate test cases:

Get some graph paper or turn lined paper sideays. Label vertical lines 00 to 24. Then draw in patterns of overlapping "meetings". You should be able to identify patterns of meetings that should be tested.

It might look like this:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
             ------------- (4 to 8)
                      ---- (7 to 8)
                                              --- (3 pm to 4 pm)
```

Which becomes:

```
03 60       <- Also try different lengths of desired meeting
04 00 08 00
07 00 08 00
15 00 16 00
```

For example,

- lines that don't overlap.
- lines that overlap only partially.
- lines where one completely overlaps the other.
- lines where one starts where the other stops.
- lines that are identical.
- lines starting at midnight (or ending at midnight)
- 1 line only
- 2 lines only
- many lines
- some lines exactly on the hour and some not on the hour (do beginning and ending both)

Turn those lines into test cases but handle the additional cases relating to the order of entry:

- situations where the meetings are all in order of start time. (or of end time)
- situations where the meetings are in reverse order.
- situations where the meetings are mixed up order. Some ascending. Some descending.